# What's the fastest way to load big image on iPhone?

Tags: objective-c

HI there,

I am building a scrollview which swipes through 100 images of houses.
It works. But.... For every image viewed the allocated memory increases by 2.5 MB. In the end the app crashed because it ran out of memory.

I use the code for decompress the image.....
- (void)decompress {
    const CGImageRef cgImage = [self CGImage];

```
const int width = CGImageGetWidth(cgImage);
const int height = CGImageGetHeight(cgImage);

const CGColorSpaceRef colorspace = CGImageGetColorSpace(cgImage);
const CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(
                                                   NULL, /* Where to store the data. NULL = don’t care */
                                                   width, height, /* width & height */
                                                   8, width * 4, /* bits per component, bytes per row */
                                                   colorspace, kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipFirst);

CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height), cgImage);
CGContextRelease(context);
```

}

but its not working,very time to take load the image.

Comment: what is the dimension of the image ?

Comment: Why don't you load it lazily?

Comment: Dimension 300*404 resolution 162.99

Comment: the images are get from server

Answer (score 0):

I also face the same problem The solution I opted was I resize the image in 320*460 dimension and then the image size become approx 50 kb not more than that.You can also do the same thing.

Code for resizing image:-

suppose you have your image in image variable of UIImage and new image is stored in editedImage which is also UIImage object.

```
if (self.image.size.height>460 || self.image.size.width>320) {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(320,480));
        [self.image drawInRect: CGRectMake(0, 0,320,480)];
         self.editedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext(); 

        NSLog(@"smallImage%f",self.editedImage.size.height);
        NSLog(@"smallImage%f",self.editedImage.size.width);
    }
    else {
        self.editedImage=self.image;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do some memory optimization. Here is a logic to save memory but you need to implement it your self. Don't add all the images to scrollview just add initally 5 images. Suppose user is viewing image1 and now he reaches to image3 when user reaches image 3 remove image1 from scrollView so that the memory can be freed. And as user scrolls forward add next images like when user is on image4 add image6 and do vice versa. When user is goes from image4 to image3 remove image6 from memory. This way there is only 5 images will be in memory.

Answer (score 0):

Three ways:

```
  1: Trying Apple's sample code called "StreetScroller", then you'll get to know how to make scrollview work definitely.

  2:Create thumbnails for large images and save to your own directory. Then read them from  url.

 3: Use UIpageviewcontroller
```